# Creating a form that directs users to specific URL based on results

Tags: javascript, php, forms, input

I need to develop a screening survey that directs the job seeker to a specific URL based on their answers. At the end of the screening it will say "Based on your answers, we think the following position is the perfect fit for you" and it will list that position. The user will then click "submit" which will re-route them to the application for that position.

I also need the survey, with the answers recorded, emailed to an address for HR when the user clicks "submit" and is routed to the application.

What is the best way to achieve this? How can I get started?

Comment: I would like to learn to program and do this myself. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to change the action of a form, is to use jQuery to change it based upon your results, and then submit will achieve your results.

If the results are returned, via another page (i.e. the submit posts to another page), you may want to redirect via meta tag.

Generally, if you are redirecting after returning the results, both a meta tag, with a suitable timeout and a link that the user can click would be appropriate.

This example may be instructive assuming a form with an id="selectsearch":

```
$("#selectsearch").change(function() {
  var action = $(this).val() == "people" ? "user" : "content";
  $("#search-form").attr("action", "/search/" + action);
});
```